# Check caching images code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, caching

I have code to cache images in MVC action, but I don't understand what is really required and what is redundant. Could you please check this and tell me your opinion?

```
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(ApplicationSettings.CacheDuration));
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Length", imageContent.Length.ToString());
Response.Cache.VaryByParams.IgnoreParams = true;
Response.Cache.VaryByParams["*"] = true;
Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(false);
Response.Cache.SetMaxAge(new TimeSpan(0, 0, ApplicationSettings.CacheDuration));
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("inline; filename={0}", fileName));

Response.OutputStream.Write(imageContent, 0, imageContent.Length);
Response.Flush();

return File(imageContent, contentType);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you configurate this in the web.config instead.

```
<system.webServer>

  <staticContent>
    <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseExpires" httpExpires="Tue, 19 Jan 2038 03:14:07 GMT" />
   </staticContent>

</system.webServer>
```